# unserialize some data into an array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, serialization

I've got an issue related with getting some data from a serialized data stored in a table and to use it for queuing another table. My approach is the following, but I'm quite new to programming and it doesn't work

```
table wppg_album
id - name -   gallery_list
1 - album1 -  a:1:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"8"}
2 - album2 -  a:2:{i:0;s:2:"17";i:1;s:2:"19";i:2;s:2:"18";}
3 - album3 -  a:3:{i:0;s:2:"13";}
```

I'm stuck with getting SQL string and deserialize data in cell gallery_list for a selected id.

The album to work on is by now fixed, tell #2 i have to get `array(17,18,19)` to finally get results from galleries table.

I wrote this code but the getting of the serial data doesen't work

```
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".WPPG_TBL_ALBUM." WHERE id = 2";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $stringGalleries = mysql_fetch_object($result);
    $galleries = unserialize($stringGalleries);
    $ids = join(',',$galleries); 
    $data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".WPPG_TBL_GALLERY." WHERE id IN   ($ids)");
?>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a typo, $ and ; missing

```
$galleries = unserialize($stringGalleries);
```

also you are using mysql_fetch_object in wrong way... here is correct code

```
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".WPPG_TBL_ALBUM." WHERE id = 2";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($galleriesRow = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
        $galleries = unserialize($galleriesRow->gallery_list);
        $ids = join(',',$galleries); 
        $data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".WPPG_TBL_GALLERY." WHERE id IN (" . $ids. ")");
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the hint mate. But it was only a retyping error... doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works like a charm. This solved my problem. I'm new do I have to add somewhere [solved] or something like that? Thank you again